# Vagrant: Windows host and Windows guest - how to restrict smb share?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, smb, shared-directory, vagrant-windows

I have a Windows 7 host and a Windows Server 2016 guest.

I have the following line in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "c:/vagrant", type: "smb", smb_username: "xxx", smb_password: "xxx"
```

Doing a `vagrant up` makes the folder containing the`Vagrantfile` (on the host) readable for everyone. How can I restrict this to the vagrant guest?

Answer (score 0):

Putting here for visibility purpose but did not try with windows guest:

```
config.vm.synced_folder '', 'c:/vagrant',
type: 'smb',
owner: 'vagrant',
smb_username: "xxx", smb_password: "xxx",
mount_options: [dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0664"]
```